# How to add mycustom object to Ninject for IoC handling 

Tags: ninject

I have an configuration object that I store in the database. When the application starts I want to reconstitute the object from the database then have Ninject control it's lifecycle. For example "InSingletonScope" and when ever another object requests this object it will come from the Ninject kernel.

Something like:

```
Bind(myInstance).ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options

1. `Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(foo)` if the object is known at the time you create the binding
2. `Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(ctx => SomeCallToCreateToObject())`
3. `Bind<IFoo>().ToProvider<FooProvider>()` and implement your own provider